# recursion practice : rewriting DOM methods

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am doing a practice for recursive function and trying to write DOM methods like getElementsByClassName.

I understand that recursion consists of base case and recursive case but not sure how to basically make them. If I am writing a function like below, what is a good mind set I can try when coming up with a base and recursive case.

```
var getElementsByClassName = function(className) {
  //basecase
  //recursive case
}
```

Please note that I do not expect a completed solution here but just want to get some thoughts from your experience. Thanks tons in advance.

Comment: 1. get document direct children

Comment: 이거 보세요..
http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/js-getelementsbyclassname.shtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward. Let me know if you have any questions with the following code.

```js
var getElementsByClassName = function(className, parent, results) {
  //setup optional parameters
  results = results || [];
  parent = parent || document.body;
  
  //basecase
  if (parent.classList.contains(className))
    results.push(parent);
  
  //recursive case
  for(var i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
    results.concat(getElementsByClassName(className, parent.children[i], results));
  }
  
  return results;
}

console.log(getElementsByClassName("one"));
console.log(getElementsByClassName("two"));
console.log(getElementsByClassName("three"));
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="one two"></div>
<div class="two three"></div>
```

Comment: oh my eyes... but this seems perfect.. :)